# Uploading a file along with other parameters in ASP.NET MVC, Web API and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I want to upload and save  a file along with other user input data having datatype int,string and datetime. I would like save the file to the hard-drive and save the path and other input data in the SQL Server database table. I am getting `AggregateException` whenever I am trying to do both together. I am new to ASP.NET MVC and Web API.

Below is my action method in ASP.NET MVC project.

```
public ActionResult AddOrEdit(mvcCandidate cn)
{
    if (cn.ID == 0)
    {
        if (cn.cvFile.ContentLength != 0)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cn.cvFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(cn.cvFile.FileName);
            filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") + extension;
            cn.path = "~/Uploads/" + filename;
            filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), filename);
            cn.cvFile.SaveAs(filename);
        }
        else
            cn.path = "";
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Candidates", cn).Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            var ch = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }         
    }
}
```

And this is the action method in WebAPI project

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCandidate(Candidate candidate)
{
    db.Candidates.Add(candidate);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = candidate.ID }, candidate);
}
```

The model class is as below:

```
public class mvcCandidate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Adress { get; set; }    
    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "CV")]
    public string path { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase cvFile { get; set; }           
    public virtual mvcCompany Company { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Mmm...so `PostAsJsonAsync` actually calls your `PostCandidate` method?

Comment: yes.MVC  and WepAPI are two seperate projects in same solution.Globalvariables is the static class setting httpclient details.

Answer (score 1):

I had struggled a lot to save file with data when dealing with Web API, so I managed to solve this problem by taking the properties and the file from the current HttpContext, I know using binding is much more easier, however this way worked for me, so the controller (API controller code) for saving file is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveFileWithData()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            #region Get entity data
            var entity = new EntityClass();
            entity.Name = httpRequest.Params["name"];

            //here you put the saving code into entity framework aka Context.Entity.Add(entity); Context.SaveChanges();

            #endregion

            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var myFile = httpRequest.Files[0];

                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"~/Files/{ myFile.FileName}");
                //Set the file into server
                myFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

And when submitting the data from the client I had used Multipart form as following:

[image: Test API using RESTFull client]